# How to load multiple scenes on demand in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to build a game with 10 levels. So if each scene is one level, how do i load the next level and delete the previous one?

I'm trying to avoid loading all the assets and scene on page load.

ThankYou :)

Comment: Way too broad to answer

Comment: Do you have any examples were multiple scenes are loaded on demand?

Comment: 2pha is right. But IMHO the answer is in your question: remove all objects of current level from your scene, add objects of a new level.